# Compare two arrays and find items that are missing in second array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have 2 arrays that they are identical at first but the user may remove (not able to add but just remove) items from the second array. I want to find items that are in the first array but not in the second one.

I can think of several ways to do this, but as these arrays can be very large, I'm curious to find out if anyone can offer a more efficient way:

```
$.grep( firstArray, function( n, i ){
  return $.inArray(n, secondArray) == -1;
});
```

Comment: Please share those two arrays

Comment: If it works I think your way is quite efficient

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the arrays have the same order, then you could filter with an index as closure.

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3],
    array2 = [2, 4, 6, 7, 2],
    missing = array1.filter((i => a => a !== array2[i] || !++i)(0));
    
console.log(missing);
```

Comment: This is imposing additional restrictions and also far less readable than Christos' answer.

Comment: @connexo, the mentiond answer relies on unique values, which may not be given.

Comment: @NinaScholz great answer, [Performance Comparison](https://jsfiddle.net/x4p0muac/23/)

Comment: @NinaScholz , could you please explain this part , a => a !== array2[i] || !++i)(0) ,thanks

Comment: it is a closure over `i` and this returns a function with `a => ...` the function body filters out the values of `array2` in the given order. this requires a check and if unequal it returns `true` or `false` by incrementing the index and taking logical not of it. the advantage of it over the `includes/indexOf` solutions, this aswer respects the order, if more same values are included.

Comment: I'd like to know the significance of the `(0)` and if that is what allows you to build your closure over `i`. The only way I know to gain access to both the array element and the index is to use the first two filter parameters: `.filter((a,i) => …)`, and the `(0)` just threw me for a loop completely (pun not initially intended)

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell, i need `i` for `array2`. if `i` would be the index of `array1`, it does not work to filter without an additional offset.

Comment: @Nina that part makes sense to me. What's really throwing me is the `0`

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell, it is the start value for `i`.

Comment: @Nina thanks! Do you know where I can find documentation for that `(0)` after the filter's callback function? `.filter((i => …)(0))`. Thanks!

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell, it is an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8228281/1447675) with a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1447675) over `i`.

Comment: If you're still around... This would be great to post to the question this is marked as a duplicate of. I see a 2x-10x speed increase over using `filter` and a binary search (instead of `includes`). Probably a different algorithmic complexity...

Comment: I still don't understand how it works, tho... :)

Answer (score 20):

You could try to make use of `filter` and `indexOf` array methods as below:

```js
var firstArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var secondArray = [3,4,6];

var result = firstArray.filter(item => secondArray.indexOf(item) == -1);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I don't get why people downvote correct answers. If you have no clue, simply shut up and learn. This is the correct answer.

Comment: As efficiency was explicitly mentioned by the author: Assuming sorted arrays one might want to do a binary search

Answer (score 2):

Do a `.filter` on the array and check if the array 2 does not have the element using `.includes`

```js
var a1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var a2 = [1,3,5];

var absent = a1.filter(e=>!a2.includes(e));

console.log(absent);
```

Comment: Thanks. let me check the performance time of these algorithms. because actually, I know a way to do it but looking for better performance.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani yea but according this is a small and fast enough code to make this task done. `.includes` is better than `.indexOf` performance wise if you just need to check array contains an element or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
function arr_diff (a1, a2) {
var a = [], diff = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
    a[a1[i]] = true;
}
for (var i = 0; i < a2.length; i++) {
    if (a[a2[i]]) {
        delete a[a2[i]];
    } else {
        a[a2[i]] = true;
    }
}
for (var k in a) {
    diff.push(k);
}
return diff;
```

}

Use this function to get difference between two sets.
A:Set 1
B:Set 2
A-B:Elements that are present in A but, not in B
Basic set theory

Comment: your answer has great performance, but as I can only mark one answer, I chose Nina's as its shorter. +1

Answer (score 0):

> As user can delete items. So you can add those deleted items in a different array.

```
var deltedItems = [];
var position = 0;

function onDeleteItem(value){
   deltedItems[position] = value;
   position++;
}
```

Here, you can find all your deleted items in ***`deltedItems`*** variable.
By using this logic you can eliminate search cost of your program.